# Como fazer um link do meu site seja aberto somente quando clicado na mesma pagina?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, redirecionamento

Estou tentando fazer um plugin editor de arquivos html, css, js e php, meu problema vem que depois que ele lê todos os arquivos ele cria um link para editar o meu arquivo criado e vai a uma outra pagina só que eu quero que quando o link seja clicado ele ao invés de redirecionar o editor ele abra na mesma pagina.

Comment: Amigo, não entendi o que você está tentando fazer, poderia explicar melhor? Sem ver o código do que o seu plugin está fazendo, também fica difícil adivinhar aonde é que pode estar o problema nele.

Answer (score 1):

Podes dividir partes do código por if/else, por exemplo:

```
if(isset($_POST['formulario']))
{
   // código após formulário ou link ser submetido
}
else               
{
    // código do formulário ou link
}
```

Desta forma controlas o fluxo do código e consequentemente o que aparece na mesma página.

Answer (score 0):

Bem você pode usar Frameset no html bem mais fácil. Ou pode criar um esquema em php tipo:

```
$ac = 1;
```

Quando clicar no botão editar, sua pagina vai adicionar `$ac + 1` e você vai continuar na mesma pagina só que na forma de edição.

```
if($ac == 1){
  //ler ou inserir dados;
} else if ($ac == 2){
  //editar dados;
}
```